# Best practice to manage File-Paths in python

Tags: python, file, path

in my python-Projects I often use a `/data`-directory where I store resources.

I now want to access these resources from different scripts, one option I see is to use the relative path of the file:

```
open('./../data/myFile.csv')
```

The problem here is that it doesn't use the path relative to the directory of the pyhton script but to the path relative to the directory in which i run python. I already had a lot of problems with that.

What works better for me is using

```
scriptDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
join(scriptDir, './../data/myFile.csv')
```

Is there any better solution to my problem? I so far never saw my solution so I'm wondering if I am missing somehing or if there is any better aproach.

Thanks :)

Comment: Consider using [`importlib.resources`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.resources) to load data files from a Python package. This does require that you start thinking in terms of "packages" and "modules" instead of "directories".

Answer (score 1):

A smart way to do that is to export an `environment variabile` or to set a constant in a `config.ini` or `settings.py` with the base path you want and concatenate it to `data/myFile.csv`

Like so:

settings.py

```
BASE_PATH = "/your/directory"
```

main.py

```
from settings import BASE_PATH
os.path.dirname(f"{BASE_PATH}/myFile.csv")
```

You may also launch your python code through a bash script where you do this:

```
export BASE_PATH=/your/directory
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
python3 main.py
deactivate
```

And in the main.py:

```
import os
base_path = os.environ["BASE_PATH"]
```